# Writing dictionary keys to a csv file based on common key and column value

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have two CSV files that I need to join. One file contains part of the information I want. I created a dictionary of the information I need from CSV 1 and need to write that Dictionary to CSV 2. I would like to write the keys of the dictionary to their appropriate ID in CSV 2.

How can I write the dictionary to the CSV2? My code populates each entry of the pet column with the same value.

Examples of the dictionary, CSV2 and output CSV are provided to provide interpretability of the code.

Code below

```
Dictionary
{'511': 'Dog', '611': 'Cat'}

CSV
ID,   Location,   Country
511,  Stack,      USA
611,  Overflow    Mexico 
711,  Stack       USA

Expected CSV
ID,   Location,    Country,    Pet
511,  Stack,       USA,        Dog
611,  Overflow,    Mexico,     Cat
711,  Stack        USA,  

Output Generated CSV
ID,   Location,    Country,    Pet
511,  Stack,       USA,        Dog
611,  Overflow,    Mexico,     Dog
711,  Stack        USA,        Dog

def readfile(filename):
    global map 
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        map = {}
        reader = csv.reader(file)               
        for row in reader:
            #print row[0]
            key = row[0]
            if key in map:
                pass
            map[key] = row[1:]
    file.close()
    return True
            

#print map.keys()

def writefile(filename):
    Location = 'Location'
    tmpfile = filename + '_tmp.csv'
    
    with open(filename, 'rb') as input:  
        with open(tmpfile,'w+b') as output:
            dreader = csv.DictReader(input, delimiter=',')
            fieldnames = dreader.fieldnames
            fieldnames.append(Location)
            
            print('I am here 1')   
            csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(output,fieldnames, delimiter = ',')
            
            #csvwriter.writeheader()
            try:
                csvwriter.writeheader()

            except AttributeError:
                    headers = []
                    for h in fieldnames:
                        headers.append((h,h))
                        csvwriter.writerow(dict(headers))
            print('I am here 2')
                
            try:
                for row in dreader:
                    for col in row:
                        if col is None: continue
                    s = row[col]
                    if s is not None:
                        row[col] = s.replace('"', '\'').replace('\\','\\\\').strip()
                        if row[col] == "NULL": 
                            row[col] = ''
                        
                        for key,value in map.iteritems():
                            if len(value) == 1 and key == 'ID':
                               pass
                            else:
                                row[Location] = value[0]
                
       # w.writeheader()
                    csvwriter.writerow(row)
                
        #print('I am here')
            except Exception: 
                    print ('Could not write appropriate value')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import csv

dic = {"511": "Dog", "611": "Cat"}

with open("in.csv", "r") as f_in, open("out.csv", "w") as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    headers = next(reader)
    writer.writerow(headers + ["Pet"])

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row + [dic.get(row[0], "")])
```

This creates `out.csv` with content:

```
ID,Location,Country,Pet
511,Stack,USA,Dog
611,Overflow,Mexico,Cat
711,Stack,USA,
```

Comment: is this python 2 or 3? I'm using python 2. But when I try to incorporate your logic I get an empty file with header only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv
d = {'511': 'Dog', '611': 'Cat'}

with open("temp.csv", "r") as input_file, open("temp1.csv", "w+") as output_file:
    input_csv = csv.DictReader(input_file, delimiter=",")
    output_csv = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=input_csv.fieldnames + ["Pet"])
    output_csv.writeheader() and output_csv.writerows({**row, **{"Pet": d.get(row.get("ID"))}} for row in input_csv)
```